# XSLT transformation For Each

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, foreach

can you please help me with XLST transformation ?

My input XML file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<file>
<line>
    <entry>A1</entry>
    <entry>B1</entry>
    <entry>C1</entry>
    <entry>D1</entry>
</line>
<line>
    <entry>A2</entry>
    <entry>B2</entry>
    <entry>C2</entry>
    <entry>D2</entry>
</line>
<line>
    <entry>A3</entry>
    <entry>B3</entry>
    <entry>C3</entry>
    <entry>D3</entry>
</line>
</file>
```

My desired output is:

```
 <groupA>
    <observation value="A1" />
    <observation value="A2" />
    <observation value="A3" />
 </groupA>
 <groupB>
    <observation value="B1" />
    <observation value="B2" />
    <observation value="B3" />
  </groupB>
 <groupC>
    <observation value="C1" />
    <observation value="C2" />
    <observation value="C3" />
 </groupC>
 <groupD>
    <observation value="D1" />
    <observation value="D2" />
    <observation value="D3" />
 </groupD>
```

Thank you very much for any advise.

I would like to group the entry by its position. 
The line "groupX" can be written by hand.

I know how to use for each cycle, but I dont know how to nest 2 cycles into each other in order to get the desired output. I hope the input file code and the desired code is clear.

If you imagine the input file as a table it is basically statement for-each-column (unfortunatelly it doesnt exists :)  ).

Thanks 
Martin

Comment: Do you want to group the `entry` elements by their position, or by their first letter? Also note, your desired output is not well-formed. You have a opening `<file>` and `<groupA>` tags, but not closing tags. Can you correct that please? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thank you for advise. I have corrected my question. It is groupping by position.

Comment: So which version of XSLT, which XSLT processor do you use or can you use? As you have asked for help "to group", have you tried grouping constructs like `xsl:for-each-group`?

Comment: it is version 1.0. and I am using processor Saxon-PE 9.8.0.12.... Yes, I tried     xsl:for-each-group, but I dont think it is the way.

Comment: So Saxon 9.8 which is an XSLT 3 processor but XSLT version 1.0? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, you are right. It is version 2, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming XSLT 2 or 3 it is a positional grouping task that can be solved with `for-each-group`:

```
  <xsl:template match="file">
      <xsl:variable name="size" as="xs:integer" select="count(line[1]/entry)"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="line/entry" group-by="position() mod $size">
          <xsl:variable name="index" as="xs:string">
              <xsl:number format="A" value="position()"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:element name="group{$index}">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

Full XSLT 3 stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="file">
      <xsl:variable name="size" as="xs:integer" select="count(line[1]/entry)"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="line/entry" group-by="position() mod $size">
          <xsl:variable name="index" as="xs:string">
              <xsl:number format="A" value="position()"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:element name="group{$index}">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry">
      <observation value="{.}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2CF/3

You could also do it in XSLT 1 or later by processing the `entry` elements of the first `line` to form a "group" and then process all with the same index to populate the group:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="file">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="line[1]/entry" mode="group"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry" mode="group">
      <xsl:variable name="index">
          <xsl:number format="A" value="position()"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
      <xsl:element name="group{$index}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="../../line/entry[position() = $pos]"/>
      </xsl:element>     
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry">
      <observation value="{.}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2CF/2